# ServiceStack OrmLiteAuthRepository UpdateUserAuth fails when password has not changed

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I'm not able to update UserAuth  through the UpdateUserAuth method in [OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Server/Auth/OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs) in case the password has not changed and comes as null. In fact the UpdateUserAuth method takes in consideration the password being null for calculating hash and salt - it would work if the ValidateNewUser(newUser, password) was not called in the first line. The ValidateNewUser checks whether the password is null or empty and throws. 
it looks like a bug and I'm not sure how to workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UpdateUserAuth` is a public facing API so requires a password to ensure only the user is able update their own profile.

But I've just added a new internal API for OrmLiteAuthRepository [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/40ae0b7d2b54bed3e8ce08eb60f9050bae91ea1c) which you can use internally to update the user details without a password with this API:

```
IUserAuth UpdateUserAuth(IUserAuth existingUser, IUserAuth newUser)
```

Comment: I hadn't taken into account the scenario where only the user can update their profile and the password would always be needed to confirm the identity. Anyway the change you made helps a lot in the scenario where an admin needs to manage users, such as mine. Thanks a lot for the super fast response!